# How to get a power output from raspberry Pi 3 B+

Tags: power, pigpio, pi-3b+

I'm pretty new to these electronics so i'm trying to figure out if I could take a 5V power output from the Pi3 B+. I'm such a noob that I can't figure where the GND and a GPIO with a 5V could be?

Comment: All the Pi GPIO are 3V3.  They can not supply or sink 5V.  Connecting a GPIO to 5V will likely destroy the GPIO and the Pi.  You CAN use a pin connected to the 5V rail (but that is NOT a GPIO).  https://pinout.xyz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a neat picture showing the Raspberry Pi pinouts from [book.webofthings.io](https://webofthings.org/book/):

[image]

They are the same on the 3B+. You can use any pin called "5V" (i.e. 2 and 4) as +5V positive and any pin called "GND" as ground/negative. You don't want to use a GPIO pin at all for this as per @joan's comment